# PHP if Statement with OR

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

I seem to be having a mysterious problem with the use of `OR` or `||` in a PHP `if` statement. My code is this:

```
if ($region=='ibiza' || 'mallorca' || 'menorca' || 'andalucia' || 'basque' || 'cataluna' || 'centralspain' || 'greenspain' || 'pyrenees' || 'rioja' || 'valencia') {
    $GoTo = "/spain/".$region.".php";    
}
```

No matter what value I give to `$region`, `$GoTo` always comes out as `/spain/$region.php` ie the first if loop always evaluates as "true". There are other ways I could do this, but I don't see why this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer @Fluffeh posted is correct. Edit: @Findus explanation is also correct.

if you want to be lazy you can do it like this:

```
if(in_array($region,array('ibiza','mallorca','menorca','...','..'))){}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I was writing after my initial post :)

Comment: @MattHumphrey yeah but to be honest the main reason I do it: because im lazy

Comment: i'm a selfthought programmer, but these questions always make me wonder did you even read a tutorial/blog/item/thing on the subject, in this case if statements.... because this stuff is easy to find on google.

Comment: I'll opt for this rather than Fluffeh's solution, just because it seems more readily understandable when I come back to it later. Thanks to all for the assistance: 5 answers in 8 minutes. Incredible!

Comment: Yes, user338128, I had done quite a lot of searching before coming here. I didn't see anything that said that my shortcut use of || wouldn't work, and I thought I had seen it elsewhere being used. With hindsight, obviously not.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use an or statement like this:

```
if ($region=='ibiza'||$region=='mallorca'||$region=='menorca'....)
```

But in your case, you might want to use `in_array()`

```
$locals=array(ibiza','mallorca','menorca','andalucia','basque','cataluna','centralspain','greenspain','pyrenees','rioja','valencia')
if (in_array($region, $locals)) {
    $goto="something...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because the statement 'mallorca' (and the ones following) evaluates to true. 
you should use a comparison, like $region == "mallorca", and similar for all the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can simlify your code like this:

```
<?php
    $selectedRegions1 = array('ibiza','mallorca','menorca','andalucia','basque','cataluna', 'centralspain','greenspain','pyrenees','rioja','valencia');
    $selectedRegions2 = array('brittany','burgundy','alps','aquitaine','loire','languedoc', 'paris','provence');
    $selectedRegions3 = array('grancanaria','lapalma','lanzarote','tenerife');
    $selectedRegions4 = array('atlas','essaouira','fez','marrakech');
    if (in_array($region, $selectedRegions1 )) {
       $GoTo = "/spain/".$region.".php";
    }elseif(in_array($region,$selectedRegions2)) {
        $GoTo = "/france/".$region.".php";
    }elseif (in_array($region,$selectedRegions3)) {
        $GoTo = "/canaries/".$region.".php";
    }elseif (in_array($region,$selectedRegions4)) {
    $GoTo = "/morocco/".$region.".php";
    }
?>
```

The problem with your code was that you forgot '$region ==' after the '||':

```
if ($region=='ibiza'|| $region=='mallorca'|| $region=='menorca'|| $region=='andalucia'|| $region=='basque'|| $region=='cataluna'|| $region=='centralspain'|| $region=='greenspain'|| $region=='pyrenees'|| $region=='rioja'|| $region=='valencia')
```

Comment: I didn't forget '$region=='; I just thought I didn't need it. Anyway, the code is now modified and the page is up and working so thanks again to all who took the trouble to reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have write if statement like this

```
if ($region=='ibiza'|| $region=='mallorca'|| $region=='menorca'|| $region=='andalucia'|| $region=='basque'|| $region=='cataluna'|| $region=='centralspain'|| $region=='greenspain'|| $region=='pyrenees'|| $region=='rioja'||$region=='valencia') {
$GoTo = "/spain/".$region.".php";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harry (and Findus). I thought I could reduce the length of the if statement by my method, but obviously not! At least I now have it confirmed that I just cannot do that.